# ¿Como hacer la autenticación de firebase en proyecto Kotlin para LogIn?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-auth

Tengo el problema que al seguir con la integración de Firebase justo en el **Check current auth state** me salta un problema en la linea **mAut = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();** diciendo que tengo un fallo en mis dependencias, he revisado y no he encontrado en que estoy errando.

Mi Activity lo tengo apenas con este código (La linea comentada es la que tiene el error)

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //mAut = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
```

Adjunto pantalla para que se entienda mejor

[image: Captura de mi activity_sign_up, donde presento el problema]

No se si me falte importar una dependencia mas o que este mal. Saludos y gracias.